# $.ajax on Windows Phone 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm having some weird issue with Jquery's `.ajax` and `.get` on Windows Phone 8 and 8.1 in a Phonegap app that uses JQuery Mobile.

The following works on iOS and Android but fails silently on WP8.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: updateurl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        alert("Done")
    })
    .fail(function () {
        alert("error");
    })
    .always(function () {
        alert("complete");
    });
```

The `.get` equivalent fails similarly.

The server responds with a 200 so I know the request is being sent but none of the callbacks ever fire.

Removing JQuery Mobile fixes the issue but is not an option.

Currently using Phonegap 3.5.0, JQuery 1.11.1, JQM 1.4.3

Also tested JQuery 1.7.2, JQM 1.3.2

I cant seem to find anybody else experiencing this issue. All other similar issues seem to be resolved by adding the JQM flags `$.support.cors = true;` and `$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPage = true;` but this has no effect and doesn't seem to be a cross domain issue anyway.

I've also tried using `promise.js` as described [here](http://www.vilepickle.com/blog/2013/04/30/00172-jquerys-ajax-and-cordova-dont-play-well-anymore#.U8ji6vldW31) but this also fails in the same manner.

Has anybody experienced this and found a solution?

Comment: Hi @DaleFraser. We ended up rebuilding this app from scratch natively. It's actually fairly simple if you've ever done any .NET dev

Answer (score 0):

**Could this be an illusion due to aggressive caching on the client side?**

I was having a similar-sounding issue. In my case, I was making a POST request to add a new item and then (once complete) doing a GET to retrieve the updated state. I saw the POST going through but my UI wasn't updating.

It turned out in my case that the subsequent GET was using the cached result--adding "cache: false" to the options on my $.ajax call solved my problem.